# How to create a git patch from the differences between 2 repos but keep the history?

Tags: git

The code in our repo was originally a copy of a download of the source rather than a git clone (the repo wasn't available at the time) So when doing a git blame, a lot of the files are the author who downloaded the code.

We have since made a lot of changes to the code.

But we now have access to the original repo, so I'd like to add the git history from the original repo. I just wondered if this was possible?

If I do

```
cd originalrepo
git checkout taggedversionineed
git log
```

Copy the last commit hash

```
cd ../ourcode
git remote add upstream ../originalrepo
git fetch upstream
git checkout develop
git diff taggedversionhash
```

It happily shows the differences between the 2 but without the history.

If I try

```
git format-patch taggedversionhash --stdout > ../mypatch.patch
```

It seems to add all the commits, not just the code differences. So when I do

```
git checkout -b feature_updatehistory taggedversionhash
git am < ../mypatch.patch
```

I get lots and lots of

```
Applying: commitmessage
error: patch failed: filename:387
error: filename: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0001 commitmessage
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /home/username/www/mycode/.git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

The files are exactly the same, but our file is from the downloaded source, the commit in the patch is from the original repo.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cherry-pick the changes from your branch with the lost history onto the branch cloned from the now available repo?

Comment: I think that's the route I will need to take but there are a lot of them.

Comment: Can't you use `git cherry-pick ..branch` to get all changes at once? Or is the problem that you expect many conflicts?